# How to import mocked data for a test without references issues when using the same mocked object/array several times

Tags: javascript, angular, unit-testing, reference

I'm trying to run some tests for angular. To do so I have complex objects (objects within objects) stored in a separate file with my other mocked data.

Every mocked object is associated to an export in the mocked data file.

In the test file I import the objects I need for my tests. Except, sometimes I have to use the same mocked data for several tests. Several tested functions are using the same data and are modifying their input data.

So my issue is that I "load" my mocked data, I use them in a test, the test changes the data, data isn't in the proper "state" for the other tests needing the mocked data.

Using a library to deep clone the mocked data is not feasible in my case.

I know that creating a recursive method (or using json parse+stringify) can fix my issue but I'd like to know if there are other options available. Like re-importing the data from the file maybe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I used a recusrive function to clone any combination of complex objects/arrays

```
    public clone(obj: any): any {
        if (null == obj || 'object' !== typeof obj) return obj;
        const copy = obj.constructor();
        if (Array.isArray(obj)) { // property value is an array
            for( const val of obj) {
                if('object' === typeof val) {
                    copy.push(this.clone(val));
                } else {
                    copy.push(val);
                }
            }
        } else {
            for (const attr of Object.keys(obj)) {
                if('object' === typeof obj[attr]) { // property value is an object
                    copy[attr] = this.clone(obj[attr]);
                } else {
                    copy[attr] = obj[attr];
                }
            }
        }
        return copy;
    }
```

I also think that dynamic import could help with this issue by importing the mockedData every time it is needed fresh as new.